# Dispatch event `click` on plot options of pie highchart generate a redraw of chart.

Tags: highcharts

actually I have an issue when I dispatch the event `click` on plot options of pie due to this generate a redraw of the chart. On my configuration I have this:

```
plotOptions: {
   pie: {
     events: { click: e => this.onClick(e) },
     ...
}
```

And below this function to emit the selected value:

```
// Catch the event on click a plot area.
onClick(event): void {
    // Emit an event with information of selected plot.
    this.plotSelected.emit(event);
}
```

And when I clicked on some point of the pie chart then all chart redraw return me all data for point in null values.

Comment: Actually, we would think around the general reason of why it happens, but it would be a bit overkill without the code or live example. Please provide us with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for that we will be able to debug it and try to prepare a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a solution for my problem. Basically I'm using Higcharts with RxJs and assign as data an response for a BehaviorSubject directly. I change the way to assign the series data and my problem it's solved.